# React Native Firebase ref.once never fired

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I'm running a react native project with a firebase database.

This is what I tried first:

```
firebase.database.ref("foo").once("value", function(s){console.log(s);});
```

Intuitively, I would think this would, at some point, be called, and if foo doesn't exist it'll return a null snapshot. But this *never* fires.

So then I tried:

```
var fooRef = firebase.database.ref("foo");
fooRef.once("value", function(s){console.log(s);});
```

This doesn't fire either. Neither does:

```
var fooRef = firebase.database.ref("foo");
fooRef.once("value").then(function(s){console.log(s);});
```

However,

```
var fooRef = firebase.database.ref("foo");
fooRef.set("bar");
fooRef.once("value", function(s){console.log(s);});
```

does fire. No other reads on any other key works after this--it only reads what has been written to in the previous instruction.

I spent around 5 hours trying all of firebase's troubleshooting tips and I'm more than frustrated now since this doesn't seem to work in any of the ways it claims to work. Reading/writing to users ref works fine in index.android.js, but fooRef only works in index.android.js.

Edit: adding full code below:

```
async getItems(obj, end_id) {
        uid = await AsyncStorage.getItem("@user:uid");
        console.log("User id: " + uid)
        console.log("App: " + firebase.database().app.name);
        var listening = true;
        firebase.database().ref("/user/" + uid + "/seen").once("value", function (snapshot) {
            console.log("Got snapshot for seen reference.")
            data = snapshot.val();
            discount = data.split(",");
            console.log(discount)
            cards = []
            console.log("Waiting to populate cards...");
            listening = false;
        });
        console.log("Attempted to receive reference of seen.");
        while(listening); listening=true;
        firebase.database().ref("/users/"+uid).once("value", function(snapshot) {
            console.log("Got snapshot of users.");
            data = snapshot.val();
            if (discount.indexOf(data.id) < 0) {
                cards.unshift({
                    heading: data.title, subtitle: data.category,
                    image: data.uri, likes: data.likes,
                    id: data.id
                });
            }
            listening = false;
            waiting = false;
        });
        while (cards.length == 0); waiting = false; obj.setState({});
}
....
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    getItems(this,99999)
}
//waiting is a global variable
```

Answer (score 0):

Firebase.database is function and you need to add `/` to ref because ref is path to you database, so you should write like this

```
firebase.database().ref('/foo').once('value').then(function(s){console.log(s.val());})
```

Comment: Tried this in all the ways above, still didn't work.

Comment: @Woodworks you call getItems from constructor? can you move it to componentDidMount lifecycle method?

Comment: I reverted to the code I used when I first started getting this problem and somehow it just magically started working... I have no clue